# How to efficiently reference an entire row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am working on a budget spreadsheet in which I have to pull in cell data from another external spreadsheet. I have to do this for several different sheets with massive amounts of data in the sheets, Is there a better way of referencing the cells than opening both workbooks, hitting '=' in the cell to add the data to, and then double clicking the cell in the spreadsheet cell I'm pulling the data from? Is it possible to pull in an entire row at once? By the method I mentioned, I have to do one cell at a time and it is taking forever. There has to be a better way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If they are contiguous cells, like you described doing a row at once, can you create the first cell and then copy it across the range?

Comment: I wish I could copy and then paste but I know no way of referencing external cells by copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the external reference or the first column in the row, then edit the formula to remove the dollar signs.  Then you can copy the formula into new cells (or fill right) and it will update the formula automatically.

Comment: Holy cow.....thank you so much! You guys have no idea how much time you just saved me!!!! That works like a charm.